# First click doesn't work in MenuItem - Android - ActionBarSherlock

Tags: android, actionbarsherlock

I have this activity

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;

import com.actionbarsherlock.app.SherlockActivity;
import com.actionbarsherlock.view.Menu;
import com.actionbarsherlock.view.MenuInflater;

public class AboutActivity extends SherlockActivity {
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.about);

        getSupportActionBar().setIcon(R.drawable.logo);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayOptions(0, getSupportActionBar().DISPLAY_SHOW_TITLE);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(com.actionbarsherlock.view.Menu menu) {
        MenuInflater inflater = getSupportMenuInflater();
        inflater.inflate(R.layout.menu_back, menu);
        return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    }
    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(
            com.actionbarsherlock.view.MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.back:
            AboutActivity.this.finish();
            return true;
        default:
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

And this is my R.layout.menu_back

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
    <item
        android:id="@+id/back"
        android:icon="@drawable/arrow"
        android:showAsAction="ifRoom|withText"
    />
</menu>
```

My problem is that when I first click on back button in the Menu it doesn't do anything, It works fine when I click it for the second time. Any suggestions?

Thank you

Comment: If you're using an IDE, like Eclipse, try a clean/refresh and then run it again. Sometimes, especially if things get refactored/moved around, the ids get off. You could debug it too, and see what ID is being passed to onOptionsItemSelected, and see if that matches the value in R.java. Beyond that, it's also a little odd to make your OWN back button, that could be confusing (the platform has a button for that, and it works pretty well, you could override the press for it if absolutely necessary and still finish the about activity).

Comment: did u find out why??

Answer (score 0):

Your code is working for me. But you should keep your menu xmls in menu folder instead of layout folder. And you can try return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item); in default section of your switch instruction.